# Locally make even spaces between words

Tags: itemize

I have a `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` block in the document, rendered as follows:

[image]

How can I make `1` in the first item align with `2` in the second item? I believe it is about making even spaces between the words among these two items.

Comment: Try `Group~1:` and `Group~2:`

Comment: @Sigur Just curious: what does the `~` do in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that LaTeX is stretching the spaces to make the lines justified. Sigur's suggestion of using `Group~1` won't work because that still produces an expandable space. (The same problem would occur using `\⎵` for the same reason). You could do something fancy to get the space amount and remove the shrinkability and stretchability, but the simpler solution is to write

```
\item \mbox{Group 1} ...
```

and

```
\item \mbox{Group 2} ...
```

This will cause both pieces of text to be output as text that's set to their natural widths before the shrinkability and stretchability is applied to the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: I'd say that `Group\hspace{\fontdimen2\font}1` would be overkill…  +1